# PHP: $_GET returning 'blank' data instead of what is displayed in URL

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm trying to use the $_GET command in my Laravel PHP application to retrieve a value that is displayed in the URL after a user submits a form by selecting an option from a drop down menu.  After the user makes their selection, the selected option is then displayed in the URL e.g.

**URL before selection:**

```
localhost:8000/pics_vids
```

**URL after selection:**

```
localhost:8000/pics_vids?category=tabletops
```

**Controller:**

```
if (isset($_GET['category']))
        {
            $urlcategory = $_GET['category'];

            /* Additional controller code */

            $data = compact('value1','value2', 'value3', 'urlcategory');

            $this->layout->content = \View::make('home.picsvids.pics_vids_overview', $data);

        }
```

**View:**

```
/*Output produces blank value instead of selected category */

<b>URL Category: {{ $urlcategory }}</b><br>
```

I'm not quite sure why it is appearing blank when it should return the value of the selected category.  Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: is that a url you're seeing in your browser's address bar? or just assuming it's there? there's going to be any number of mod_rewrite rules mangling the url long before php ever gets a stab at it.

Comment: `var_dump( $data );` before send to view

Comment: Marc B -> Yes that was a URL I was seeing in my browser's address bar but yes it is good to double check.  @trzyeM -> var_dump( @data) helped me understand why it was blank because I actually placed my code in the wrong section of the controller due to an 'if' condition I had set up.  The $_GET command is now working for me.  Thank you both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built in `Input::get('name of variable here');` notation to get `_GET` and `_POST` variables. Should solve your problem and will certainly make your code easier to read/maintain.